# Python how to reduce multiple lists?

Tags: python, sum, reduce, map-function

I am able to use `map` and `sum` to achieve this functionality, but how to use `reduce`?

There are 2 lists: `a`, `b`, they have same number of values. I want to calculate

```
a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+...+a[n]*b[n]
```

The working version I wrote using `map` is

```
value =  sum(map(lambda (x,y): x*y, zip(a, b)))
```

How to use `reduce` then? I wrote:

```
value =  reduce(lambda (x,y): x[0]*y[0] + x[1]*y[1], zip(a, b)))
```

I got the error "`TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable`".

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Your lambda takes two two-element tuples. That works fine when reducing the first two elements of your list, but now the next reduction will work on the result of your lambda (which is a float) and the next element of the list (which is a tuple), and your lambda can't handle that. Your lambda needs to take a number and a tuple, and seed the number with an initial value (as antonakos' answer does).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument of the lambda function is the sum so far and the second argument is the next pair of elements:

```
value = reduce(lambda sum, (x, y): sum + x*y, zip(a, b), 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

A solution using `reduce` and `map`,

```
from operator import add,mul

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

print reduce(add,map(mul,a,b))
```

Answer (score 7):

I would do it this way (I don't think you need lambda)...

```
sum(x*y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

This also seems slightly more explicit. Zip AB, multiply them, and sum up the terms.

Comment: +1, although `sum(x*y for x,y in zip(a,b))` would be also fine

Answer (score 2):

an **update** on the **accepted answer** (by @antonakos):

The ability to unpack tuple parameters was removed in **Python 3**.x

so the solution

```
value = reduce(lambda sum, (x, y): sum + x*y, zip(a, b), 0)
```

might give you a syntax error:

```
 value = reduce(lambda sum, (x,y): sum + x*y, zip(a,b), 0)
                            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To work on both **Python 2.x and 3.x**, You can **manually unpack the tuple** instead:

```
from functools import reduce
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,4,8]
value = reduce(lambda sum, xy: sum + xy[0]+xy[1], zip(a,b), 0)
print("result:", value)
```

> result: 19

Answer (score 1):

Difficulties with reduce happen when you have incorrect map.

Let's take expression: 
`value =  sum(map(lambda (x,y): x*y, zip(a, b)))`

Map is transformation. We need it to convert tuples into **simple flat** values. 
In your case it will look like:

```
map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], zip(a,b))
```

And then, if you want to express `sum` via `reduce` - it will look like:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, map)
```

So, here is [example](https://repl.it/vIK):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6] 
l = zip(a,b)
m = map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], l)
r = reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you want an inner product. use an inner product.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html

```
np.inner(a, b) = sum(a[:]*b[:])
```

Ordinary inner product for vectors:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([0,1,0])
np.inner(a, b)
```

output: 2

A multidimensional example:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape((2,3,4))
b = np.arange(4)
np.inner(a, b)
```

output: array([[ 14,  38,  62],[ 86, 110, 134]])

Comment: It is good that you mention "inner product", because that gives us some mathematical and conceptual background.